# How to declare an array initialize with an variable in C++

Tags: c++

I know this sound easy to you guys but I think this may be different

Here is my simple code in which i am getting error in declaring Array

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int top=-1,capacity=2;
int arr[capacity];

main(){
}//main
```

Comment: Sorry, C++ does not work this way. Array dimensions must be constants. Just because it's a variable that's  been initialized with some value doesn't make the array dimension a constant.

Comment: You may want to check your C++ book. There's an `int` missing before `main`.

Answer (score 1):

A fixed length array needs a compile-time constant to declare its size. You need to declare `capacity` as `const` or `constexpr` in order to use it in an array declaration, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int top = -1;
const int capacity = 2;
int arr[capacity];

main(){
}
```

If you want to define the `capacity` at runtime then you need to use a dynamic array, like `std::vector`, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int top = -1, capacity;
vector<int> arr;

main(){
    capacity = ...;
    arr.resize(capacity);
}
```

Comment: @shahmir "*sometime its work fine*" - if the variable is not a compile-time constant then it CAN'T be used to declare a fixed length array statically, period. You might be thinking of a "variable length array", which is [not legal C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/) and is a vendor-specific extension that only a few compilers support.